# Check if element exists in O(1) and minimum memory - something better than set

Tags: java, data-structures

I am writing code in java. I am traversing through the CSV file of size 50 GBS, the CSV has only one column that is a string which is like "12121213". The file is not sorted based on the ids. I have some requirements to have only unique ids I want to print. I have created a set : visitedId in which I am adding the ids, but this set is taking a lot of memory. Is there something through which I only can check "isExists" without actually storing all the data? Like I don't want to get back the set elements, I just want to check whether the id has already visited or not. Like some hashing or somethings through which I can achieve this in minimum time and memeory.

So basically I am looking for something like a hash function to which I can add the ids, which gives the same result on checking isExists.

eg:
hash.add(1)
hash.add(2)

hash generates some hash value based on 1 and 2

hash.isExists(1) -> true
hash.isExists(3) -> false

Comment: O(1)? Never. What I would do is load the whole CSV into a temporary table in that database then select distinct IDs from it. The database is already very optimized for sorting.

Comment: @RealSkeptic yes i know, but i have some requirements, i have not specified exact requirements. But i am asking whether there is something better than set to check only if exists thing. i need to do everything in memory in my requirement.

Comment: Are the IDs strings or numbers? If they are numbers, you can save a lot of memory by using a set of numbers (`Integer`, `Long`, `Double` instances) instead of as set of strings.

Comment: Perhaps sorting the file first would be an option, then you easily notice duplicates. But really, this sounds like you should just create an indexed table in the database and specify that duplicate ids are not allowed and see how fast it is. I would assume it is very fast, because database writers do that for a living

Comment: @lucidbrot i have remove data base from the question :-) . i know what you are saying but my requirement is something different i am working on redis

Comment: How frequent are duplicates? As in, are you looking at 50GB with only 100,000 unique IDs, or are duplicates pretty rare?

Comment: @templatetypedef its not only 100,000 but most data is grouped like say 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 like this, where 1 and 2 are ids

Comment: It would help if you provided more information about the IDs (how many are in a file in total, how many distinct does it contain, what is the upper and lower range, are the all integer numbers). And does the result need to be precise, or is it sufficient if 99% of the duplicates are avoided?

Comment: @Asim If the data typically contains long runs you can implement a trick of first checking if the next element is just a duplicate of the previous one before going to whatever container you end up using. In the example above 9 of 12 look-ups would be O(1). I've seen this divide time by 50 - 100 in real world cases where big runs are normal.

Comment: You could modify your initial size and load factor of a `HashSet`  to better handle collisions.  This would get you nearer to O(1) lookup but nothing like an array access.